# What is row slicing vs What is column slicing?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

Yes, I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042566/which-one-is-which-between-column-slicing-and-row-slicing) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352280/slicing-sparse-matrices-in-scipy-which-types-work-best), but I cannot still grasp my mind around it... it's a basic question.

In:

```
M[:, index]
M[index, :]
```

**Which one is *row slicing*, and which one is *column slicing*?**

And to my problem, if I want to do [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) for the columns like:

```
M[:, indexes]  # indexes is an array like [0, 4, 9]
```

**Which sparse matrix type is most efficient for doing `M[:, indexes]`, [CSR](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix) or [CSC](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csc_matrix) ?**

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, I know it's a dummy question. Please enlighten me.

Comment: first one is column slicing because it is selecting a column for all rows. Second is row slicing

Comment: Be careful here.  Sparse matrix slicing and indexing is different from `ndarray`.  It looks the same, but it is actually implemented with matrix multiplication.  So distinctions between basic v advanced indexing and copy v view don't apply.  If you are worried about speed, do your own timings.

Comment: Where did you find `_row_slicing_`.  I having seen such a method.

Comment: @hpaulj I was only giving emphasis -- I removed the underscores as that may be clearer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually neither is row/column **slicing**: those are examples of row/column **indexing** instead.

- `M[index, :]` is row indexing
- `M[:, index]` is column indexing
- `M[start:stop, :]` is row slicing
- `M[:, start:stop]` is column slicing

CSC is more efficient at retrieving entire columns: the non-zero values of a specific column and the matching row indices are internally stored as contiguous arrays in memory.

The dual is true for CSR and the retrieval of an entire row.

Comment: This makes much more sense to me. I was thinking that `:` was the slice, so that's why I was confused with `M[:, index]` being column slicing. So I guess you are saying, `:` it's not truly slicing as it just means "all", and then I'm just doing indexing of columns. -- Further, for my case, I'm not truly slicing columns only indexing (as you said). `CSC` is for my case better not exactly because this type is _better at slicing_ but more generally, because it's _better at retrieving whole columns_ -- Correct?

Comment: Yes `:` alone is a shorthand for `None:None` and means the complete slice around that axis, which is equivalent to no slicing at all ;) Yes CSC is better at retrieving whole columns (both by slicing a subset of the columns and by indexing specific columns).

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies the confusion I had with `:` and therefore answers my question :-) -- _to slice or not to slice_

Answer (score 3):

While row selection is faster for `csr` than for col selection, the difference is not big:

```
In [288]: Mbig=sparse.rand(1000,1000,.1, 'csr')
In [289]: Mbig[:1000:50,:]
Out[289]: 
<20x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2066 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [290]: timeit Mbig[:1000:50,:]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.53 ms per loop
In [291]: timeit Mbig[:,:1000:50]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.04 ms per loop

In [292]: Mbig=sparse.rand(1000,1000,.1, 'csc')
In [293]: timeit Mbig[:1000:50,:]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.16 ms per loop
In [294]: timeit Mbig[:,:1000:50]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.65 ms per loop
```

It isn't worth it to switch format

```
In [295]: timeit Mbig.tocsr()[:1000:50,:]
...
100 loops, best of 3: 2.46 ms per loop
```

Contrast this with the same slice for the dense version:

```
In [297]: A=Mbig.A
In [298]: timeit A[:,:1000:50]
...
1000000 loops, best of 3: 557 ns per loop
In [301]: timeit A[:,:1000:50].copy()
...
10000 loops, best of 3: 52.5 µs per loop
```

To complicate the comparison, indexing with an array (`numpy` advanced) is actually faster than with the 'slice':

```
In [308]: idx=np.r_[0:1000:50]    # expand slice into array
In [309]: timeit Mbig[idx,:]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.49 ms per loop
In [310]: timeit Mbig[:,idx]
1000 loops, best of 3: 513 µs per loop
```

Here the column indexing of a `csc` has a greater speed improvement.

And single row or column, `csr` and `csc` have `getrow/col` methods:

```
In [314]: timeit Mbig.getrow(500)
1000 loops, best of 3: 434 µs per loop
In [315]: timeit Mbig.getcol(500)        # 1 column from csc is fastest
10000 loops, best of 3: 78.7 µs per loop
In [316]: timeit Mbig[500,:]
1000 loops, best of 3: 505 µs per loop
In [317]: timeit Mbig[:,500]
1000 loops, best of 3: 264 µs per loop
```

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/39500986/901925 I recreated the `extractor` code that `sparse` uses to fetch rows or columns.  It constructs a new sparse 'vector' of 1s and 0s, and uses matrix multiplication to 'select' rows or columns.

Comment: After testing both csr and csc, I also didn't notice a noticeable difference between them for doing column slicing (with matrices of ~ size (1k, 15k)) -- Therefore I sticked to csr as that was the original type of my matrix.

Answer (score 2):

It's ok to get the order mixed up every once in a while, my trick is to just picture a matrix and remember that the index order counts from up to down and then from left to right: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_notation

[image: down, left]

So, since `:` means *all*, you know that `[:, i]` means all rows, and `[i, :]` all columns.

To the second part of your question: You want `M[:, indices]`, so the trick is in the name: If you loop over your columns (which you do since you specify column indices for *all* rows), then you want *compressed sparse colum* format. It says so in the docs you linked:

> Advantages of the CSC format
>
> - ...
> - efficient column slicing

Comment: Thanks. So yes, `[:, i]` is column slicing and that's why I want to use `CSC` - right?

Comment: You'll want to use CSC, yes.